# Shell: Differences from bash 3.2.57 to 4.3.41 in read -t option?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I've been running the following code on my laptop (OSX 10.11.6) and it worked as I wanted (bash version 3.2.57):

```
dir=""
thread=1
an="bla"

usage() { echo "Usage: Script -d <homedir> -t <threads> -a <bla or blubb>"
   echo " "
   echo "Options:"
                 echo "-h|?|--help     show brief help"
1>&2;
exit 1;
}

while getopts ":d:t:a:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        d)
            d=${OPTARG}
            dir=$d;;
        t)
            t=${OPTARG}
            thread=$t;;
        a)
            a=${OPTARG}
            ***(($a == "bla" || $a == "blubb")) || usage***
            an=$a;;
        :)
            echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
        *)
            usage;;
esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "${d}" ] || [ -z "${t}" ] || [ -z "${a}" ]; then
    usage
fi

***read -t 10 -p "Every parameter set as you wanted? Enter Y/y, space or ENTER! -n 1 -r REPLY***
echo ""    # (optional) move to a new line
case $REPLY in
      [yY] | "")
              echo "correct";;
      *)
              echo "Terminating"
              exit 1;;
esac
```

Trying to let it run on a linux server (Ubuntu 16.04) with the bash version 4.3.41 gave me these 3 errors (lines marked above with ***) and I don't know why:

```
sh testing_stuff.sh -d /home/ -t 2 -a bla
testing_stuff.sh: 29: testing_stuff.sh: [[: not found
testing_stuff.sh: 29: testing_stuff.sh: bla==blubb: not found
testing_stuff.sh: 45: read: Illegal option -t
```

I've changed one of the marked lines already to:

```
            a)
            a=${OPTARG}
            ***[[$a == "bla" || $a == "blubb"]] && usage***
            an=$a;;
```

But this didn't change anything. I actually don't know why this worked on my laptop without any mistake, but not on the server.

Plz let me know where I've made the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu, the default shell is `dash`.  Your script however uses `bash` features.  To fix the problem, replace:

```
sh testing_stuff.sh -d /home/ -t 2 -a bla
```

With:

```
bash testing_stuff.sh -d /home/ -t 2 -a bla
```

On Ubuntu and other debian-like systems, the default shell, `/bin/sh`, is `dash`.  Dash is POSIX-compliant, lightweight, and fast, but it does not support all of the features that the heavier `bash` supports.  If you script needs `bash`, and yours does, run it explicitly under `bash`.

Comment: Better yet, add a `#!/bin/bash` shebang line and ditch typing the shell on the command line.

Comment: Yes, I do that on my scripts.  But, the OP is using `sh script` and that overrides the shebang.

Comment: Thank you @John1024, this helped me. But I had the shebang line in it  and had to call it like you suggested. Thank you all for these helpful comments.

Comment: The shebang is only considered when you call the command directly, e.g. `testing_stuff.sh -d /home/ -t 2 -a bla` When you put `sh` in front of that, you're explicitly calling `sh` which is `dash` on Ubuntu.